# how to update druid metric's value once the segments generated through file ingestion

Tags: java, linux, apache-zookeeper, olap, druid

The [druid](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-batch.html) datasource shards in multiple intervals(segments) ingested json file.But how can i update the metric's and dimension's value of existing data.
Expecting some setup of query like SQL update in druid format.

Here is task setup sample

```js
{
   "type":"index",
   "spec":{
      "dataSchema":{
         "dataSource":"schema_sample",
         "parser":{
            "type":"string",
            "parseSpec":{
               "format":"json",
               "timestampSpec":{
                  "column":"WeekDate",
                  "format":"auto"
               },
               "dimensionsSpec":{
                  "dimensions":[
                     "_id",
                     "ItemNumber",
                     "MonthNo",
                     "Year",
                     "MonthNo",
                     "CustomerName"
                  ],
                  "dimensionExclusions":[

                  ],
                  "spatialDimensions":[

                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "metricsSpec":[
            {
               "type":"doubleSum",
               "name":"Forecast",
               "fieldName":"Forecast"
            }
         ],
         "granularitySpec":{
            "type":"uniform",
            "segmentGranularity":"WEEK",
            "queryGranularity":"NONE",
            "intervals":[
               "2014-01-01/2019-12-31"
            ]
         }
      },
      "ioConfig":{
         "type":"index",
         "firehose":{
            "type":"local",
            "baseDir":"quickstart/",
            "filter":"fr_json_data_1k.json"
         }
      },
      "tuningConfig":{
         "type":"index",
         "targetPartitionSize":5000000,
         "maxRowsInMemory":75000
      }
   }
}
```

Now as per requirement, Forecast's value will change or even other dimensions too. I was looking at [druid update existing data](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html)  ,But unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

for updating the data, you need to re-index your data for the same time period with updated values.

But in your case, it seems you have new forecast values coming, so just ingesting the new values for the new time interval should update your metric values.